# How do i simply change a sprite's image in cocos2d?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've tried

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"still.png"];
```

But I always end up with a distorted image for some reason. It's most likely because my images are not the same resolution, but for this app, they can't have the same res. How do I change the sprite's image without going through the complicated process of making a spritesheet or an animation or any of that.

Answer (score 16):

```
urSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"one.png"];
urSprite.position = ccp(240,160);
[self urSprite z:5 tag:1];

// Changing the image of the same sprite
[urSprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"two.png"]];
```

Comment: Does this example still work in cocos2d v3.0 ? xcode says "undeclares identifier 'CCTextureCache'".

Answer (score 10):

This is the most straight forward way to change the image of a sprite(if you have it loaded trough a spritesheet) this definitely works (I use it all the time in my game). mySprite is the name of the sprite instance:

> [mySprite setDisplayFrame:
>   [[CCSpriteFrameCache
>   sharedSpriteFrameCache]
>   spriteFrameByName: @"sprite1.png"]
>        ];

Comment: This is the better solution when working wit animations. Use it if animation is running and you want to stop it, just don't forget to stop the animation action.

Answer (score 6):

You would just call the *sprite.texture* function.

***Example***

**In your init method:**

```
CCTexture2D *tex1 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"still.png"];
CCTexture2D *tex2 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"anotherImage.png"];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex1];
//position the sprite
[self addChild:sprite];
```

**Then to change the image of the sprite to tex2:**

```
sprite.texture = tex2;
```

*Very simple!*

Hope this helped!

Comment: is sprite.texture = tex2 the same as sprite setDisplayFrame:frameCache spriteFrameByName

Comment: @OMGPOP Yes, I believe so. The advantage to this, though, is that you can preload the textures. It really depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In cocos2d v3, I was able to accomplish this with...

```
[mySprite setSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"two.png"]]
```

...but I have no idea if this has side effects that will hurt me in the long run. :)

Answer (score 0):

This simple one line can do your task.

```
[sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"slot.png"]];
```

Comment: what was wrong with original post ? which change you made in this ? @Ankur

Comment: highlighted the coding part.. to see the changes see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17715260/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

I use cocos2d 3.0 and this code works for me:

```
 [_mySprite setTexture:[CCTexture textureWithFile:@"myFile.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2d-x v3, you can use `my_sprite->setTexture(sprite_path);`